# Is it possible to Insert into multiple tables using a single Insert statement?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, insert-statement

I have two tables table A and table B.

I insert values in both table like this:

```
Insert Into A (Col1, Col2) Values ("1" "ABC")
Insert Into B (Col1, Col2) Values ("1" "ABC")
```

but, I want to perform this operation using single insert statement.
I used Microsoft `SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2` for this.

Can anyone please tell me is it possible?

Thanks...!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the Table name by parameter, if and only if, the column names are identical:

```
Insert Into @tableName (Col1, Col2) Values ("1" "ABC")
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is not possible with a single query. But you can try with a procedure with two insert statements. Or try an after insert trigger.